# Change is not reflected in form.isvalid() in django

Tags: mysql, django

I am working with django models. Before deploying the site to the server, I had following two columns in table:

```
total_marks_twelvth      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| obtained_marks_twelvth   | int(11)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

After uploading, I had to change `obtained_marks_twelvth` to float. Now, change reflected in table:

```
| total_marks_twelvth      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| obtained_marks_twelvth   | double        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

But, the issue is above change is not reflected while checking the form.is_valid() method in the view.

```
if form.is_valid():

        name = request.POST.get("name")

        form.save()
```

the above method returns false, and throws an error:

```
* Enter a whole number.
```

in browser.

The model earlier was:

```
total_marks_twelvth = models.IntegerField()
obtained_marks_twelvth = models.IntegerField()
```

I changed it to:

```
 total_marks_twelvth = models.IntegerField()
 obtained_marks_twelvth = models.FloatField()
```

After this I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`. It executed successfully.

So,what I am concluding here is the change is reflected in database, but not on the models. Why is it so? Please help to solve this.

Edit:

The view is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StudentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        name = request.POST.get("name")

        form.save()
        print "Form is saved successfully."
        return render(request, 'success.html',{'name' : name})
    else:
        print "Something went wrong"
        print form.errors
        return render(request, 'apply.html',{'form' : form})
```

The form is:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

This model contains a student model class:

```
class Student(models.Model):
"""here goes model for users"""

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" % ( self.name,self.enrollment_no)
 total_marks_twelvth = models.IntegerField()
 obtained_marks_twelvth = models.FloatField()
```

Looks like django is not using the latest migration, but the changes are reflected in the database.

the error I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: Please post your full form class code.

Comment: which class code? Model?

Comment: Have a look on my edits. Thanks.

Comment: Which field does the error appear against? Are you sure it appears for `obtained_marks_twelvth` and not `total_marks_twelvth`?

Comment: yes, it appears for only `obtained_marks_twelvth`, because I am changing it from int to float. It is accepting int values but not float values. Have a look on my edits.